# No Mapped Drives after un-installing Hyper-V with Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I uninstalled Hyper-V and now I can't get my Mapped Drives to work. I still have internet connectivity so I know the Network cards are OK. But If I disable the Network Card, the wireless adapter takes over and all of a sudden I get my mapped drives back. When I re-enable the Network Card. The wireless goes off and for about 5 minutes, my mapped drives work great. But after that I get the red X on them again. If I double click on them, I get a message that says "The local device name is already in use". The network trouble Shooter doesn't see anything wrong either.

Any ideas on how I can get my network drives back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly didn't remove your Hyper-V virtual switch before you uninstalled Hyper-V.

This means your network interface probably doesn't have the correct protocol bindings.  It would probably be best to install it again, remove the Virtual switch correctly, then uninstall if you want it removed.

Since removing the virtual switch didn't fix things, if you want to to try manually correcting protocol bindings this is what you would do.

- Control Panel
- Network and Internet
- Network and Sharing Center
- Change adapter settings
- Right click on adapter and go to properties.
- Typically all the boxes should be checked except the Hyper-V Virtual Switch, and the Network Adapter Multiplex protocol.

[image: protocol bindings]

Comment: Well I re-installed Hyper-V and added the Virtual Switch back. Things returned to normal. Did what you suggested and lost my mapped drives again. Added the Virtual Switch back and things work normally again. I'm just gonna keep it that way. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I added an update if you want to try again.  Also, if you want to leave Hyper-V installed, but you don't want the Hypervisor to actually load you can see how to disable the functionality here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry.aspx